# команды в командной строке (cmd)

Tags: cmd

С помощью каких команд в командной строке можно решить эти задачи?

1. При наличии двух параметров производится копирование файла с
   именем, заданным первым параметром, во второй. Если параметр
   один, то файл выдается на терминал. При другом числе параметров
   выдается ошибка.
2. Найти в реестре раздел, описывающий созданную ассоциацию для расширения `.pas` (найти в `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` раздел `.pas`, запомнить
   значение по-умолчанию – это идентификатор типа, затем найти раздел с
   таким именем в корне `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`). Создать по аналогии
   раздел, связывающий `.cpp` с `bc.exe` (или с `notepad.exe`).

Comment: 1) `IF '%%3'=='' (...` 2) `reg query` + `reg add`